# accessing relationship from model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a two tables where user table has a one to one relationship with role table

this is my user model

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

this is my role model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

this my table structure for role

[image]

this my table structure for user

[image]

how can i access in my user model the role which is equal to employee
i tried

```
User::with('role')->where('role_name','employee')->get();
```

but it has an error

```
role_name column not found
```

Comment: add error to question

Comment: User::with('role')->where('role.role_name','employee')->get();

Comment: can rephrase your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you only the users which has an employee role .

```
User::whereHas('role', function ($query) {
    $query->where('role_name', 'employee');
})->get();
```

And this will give you all the users with their employee roles if any exist

```
User::with(['role' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('role_name', 'employee');
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
User::whereHas('role', function ($query) {
    $query->where('role_name', 'employee');
})->get();
```

Details at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User::with(['role' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('role_name', 'employee');
}])->get();
```